# A block definition must have block content delimited by "{" and "}", starting on the same line as the block header

Tags: terraform

```
*
```

Error: Invalid block definition

```
  on variable.tf line 1:
   1: variable  "counte"
   2:  {

A block definition must have block content delimited by "{" and "}", starting
on the same line as the block header.
```

- 

i got this error while i'm enter terraform init command. my variable.tf is adding below, anybody know to solve this, help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kynpy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{` must be in the **same line** as `variable  "counte"`, for example

```
variable  "counte" {
   default = 1
}
```

Comment: in my case it gave me the same error when i wrote `description <value>` forgot the `=` ...